# What is the after brachah on triscuits?

Tags: halacha, blessing

First ingredient listed is rice, second is wheat.

Can I assume there is enough wheat to make a kezayis if I eat a serving or two, or since the rice is listed first, do I just make borei nefashos?

Comment: Can you taste the wheat? Rice with the taste of wheat is itself Al Hamichya / Bentching.

Comment: I remember that for Bracha Acharona poskim told about Kazait Bikde Achilat Peras, and discussed kazait of mixture or kezait of wheat

Comment: @DoubleAA is right, a mishna in chala concerning rice 
הָעוֹשֶׂה עִסָּה מִן הַחִטִּים וּמִן הָאֹרֶז, אִם יֶשׁ בָּהּ טַעַם דָּגָן, חַיֶּבֶת בַּחַלָּה, וְיוֹצֵא בָהּ אָדָם יְדֵי חוֹבָתוֹ בְּפֶסַח. וְאִם אֵין בָּהּ טַעַם דָּגָן, אֵינָהּ חַיֶּבֶת בַּחַלָּה, וְאֵין אָדָם יוֹצֵא בָהּ יְדֵי חוֹבָתוֹ בְּפֶסַח:

Comment: For those of us who do not know, how big is a triscuit?  How many would make a kezyit?

Comment: https://oukosher.org/blog/kosher-professionals/bishul-akum-tzuras-hapas/

Answer (score 1):

[Triscuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triscuit), you say, contain wheat and rice.

As @Double AA mentioned, mixture of wheat with rice is different than mixture of wheat with other ingredients. When we say "rice", we have in mind what the mishna and Gemara called "Orez". We will examine further if Poskim identified rice as Orez or not.
In [Mishna Chala, 3, 7](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01082.html#HtmpReportNum0023_L2) :

> הָעוֹשֶׂה עִסָּה מִן הַחִטִּים וּמִן הָאֹרֶז, אִם יֶשׁ בָּהּ טַעַם דָּגָן, חַיֶּבֶת בַּחַלָּה, וְיוֹצֵא בָהּ אָדָם יְדֵי חוֹבָתוֹ בְּפֶסַח. וְאִם אֵין בָּהּ טַעַם דָּגָן, אֵינָהּ חַיֶּבֶת בַּחַלָּה, וְאֵין אָדָם יוֹצֵא בָהּ יְדֵי חוֹבָתוֹ בְּפֶסַח: ‏
>
> A man who made a dough from wheat and rice, if it has taste of cereals, it is taxable for Chala and he can make mitsvat eating Matsa on Pessach with it.

We show that nothing is lacking in the mixed dough, even if the quantity of wheat is small, but sufficient to give a taste. This interpretation of the Mishna is congruent to Ramban, but some other Rishonim see the so called taste as a strong enough taste as we will examine further.

Now I will copy the comment Magen Avraham on [SA OC 208, sk 15](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1034) (in way to examine diverse components of the question):

> כך כתב הרב דוד אבודרהם בשם תלמידי רבינו יונה. שנינו במסכת חלה ‏(ג,ז)‏ העושה עיסה מן החיטין ומן האורז אם יש בה טעם דגן חייבת מן החלה ואדם יוצא בה ידי חובתו בפסח. וכתב הרב בית יוסף סימן תנ"ג, כתב **הראב"ד והרשב"א** והוא שיש בה כזית בכדי אכילת פרס. **והמגיד משנה והרמב"ן** סוברים אפילו אין בה כזית בכדי אכילת פרס. לפי שהחיטין גוררין את האורז. ודוקא באורז, אבל לא במינים אחרים, וכן דברי הרמב"ם והרא"ש. עד כאן לשונו. וידוע שדין חלה והמוציא שוין בזה לכולי עלמא, עיין סימן קס"ח סעיף י"ג דגבי חלה לחם כתיב וגבי מצה מדמה בגמרא להמוציא כדאיתא בברכות דף ל"ז עמוד ב' וגם הרמב"ם כתב בהלכות מצה: זה הכלל כל שמברכים עליו ברכת המזון אדם יוצא בו ידי חובתו ועין סוף סימן קפ"ח ואם כן מוכח דבאורז אף על גב דליכא כזית בכדי אכילת פרס, מברכים המוציא ושלש ברכות לדעת המגיד משנה וסיעתו. ובשאר מינים לא מקרי לחם לענין המוציא והוא הדין לענין ברכת המזון דכתב הרמב"ם בפרק שלישי דיש אומרים כל שמברכים עליו ברכת המוציא מברכים בסוף ברכת המזון וכל שמברכים עליו בורא מיני מזונות מברך בסוף מעין שלש חוץ מן האורז וכן הוא בירושלמי. ומיהו התם מסיים דקאי אמין שמברכים עליו ואם כן צריך עיון למה כתב כאן בתחילה המוציא ולבסוף על המחיה ולא מצינו כיוצא בזה בכולי תלמודא. וצריך לומר כיון דקיימא לן **בכל איסורין שבתורה שאם אכל מעט ושהה בכדי אכילת פרס אינו חייב, אם כן הוא הדין לענין ברכת המזון** עד שיאכל כזית בלא שהיה בכדי אכילת פרס והכא, כיון שמעורב, כזית יותר בכדי אכילת פרס, על כרחך שוהה ביניהם ולכן אינו מברך ברכת המזון והוא הדין לענין מצה, ועין מה שכתבתי בריש סימן ר"י. אבל המוציא מברך דעל כל שהוא מברך המוציא, וכן משמע קצת בלבוש. ומכל מקום קשה, כיון דאינו מצרף, אם כן גם על המחיה לא יברך, דעל שאר המינין אינו מברך רק בורא נפשות. ועוד דהא, גבי חלה, אף על פי שיש בקמח של דגן לבד שיעור חלה, אפילו הכי, אם ערבו בקמח אחר פטור מחלה אם אין בו כזית בכדי אכילת פרס, אלמא בטיל לגמרי. ויש לומר דלענין ברכה קיימא לן כל שיש בו מחמשת המינים מברך בורא מיני מזונות, אף על פי שאין בו כזית בכדי אכילת פרס, כמו שכבות בסעיף ב'. אך קשה, למה כתב אם בשלו מברך אחריו בורא נפשות. וצריך עיון. ומיהו **אם לא ערבו עם קמח, רק עם שאר מינים**, מברך בורא מיני מזונות ועל המחיה ואפילו אין בו כזית בכדי אכילת פרס כמו שכתוב בסעיף ב'. ‏

Instead of translating the text, I will try to show its structure.

1. Following some Rishonim (Rashba, Raavad), The "concentration of Wheal in a dough of Orez need to be KAP (concentration-rate) thereby to transform it in a Challa taxable.
2. Following others (Magid Mishne, Ramban), a simple taste of wheat is sufficient. This is a particularity of Orez which is "dragged" by the wheat.
3. A bread made from **rice and a bit of wheat** needs to bless Hamotsi and Birkat Hamazon according to MM & RaMBaN.
4. For mixtures of wheat with **non-Orez kitniot**,  All Rishonim agree that the mixture needs a KAP of wheat in way to make a bread requiring Hamotsi and BHM.
5. But if the amount of wheat is lower, RMBM seems to decide that the  blessing will be BMMezonot (BMM) and Me'en 3 (Al Hamichia (Ahava, Berachot, 3, 11)).
6. A difference of Criterion between First Blessing and Last Blessing is understandable. The first is not quantity related and the second is quantity related. So may be that the first is not Concentration Related and the second is Concentration Related because the concentration influences the rate of eating, which is also important as we will learn further. So, something can be Hamotsi and not Birkat Hamazon.
7. Shulchan Aruch 208, 9 mechadesh: A bread with wheat less than KAP and other Kitniot, need to bless Hamotsi and Al Hamichia.
8. The discrepancy between the Criterion for Birkat Hamazon and for Al Hamichia is strange:
9. Both are quantity-proportion related. And as for prohibited foods quantity of eating is Rated to rate. eating a "Kezayt quantity" of Isur in a "time quantity of Achilat pras": Quantity--eating Rate related.
10. So for BHM and AHM we expect the same criterion of KAP of wheat.
11. Magen Avraham wrote that a Kazait of weat must be eaten, not only of the mixture, and it must to be eaten in a time called Achilat Pras in way to blessing Hamotsi. For prohibited mixture too a Kazayit of mixture is not sufficient for Shiur Isur, they need to eat a Kazayit of Isur from the mixture (this detail needs a large development, e.g. For the Gra, without a Kezayit of weath, Bore nefashot, even if he eat many Kezeitim of the mixture.)
12. Magen Avraham doesn't Metarets, but he accepted the Psak of Shulchan Aruch for mixture of FLOUR.
13. Magen Avraham sk 9 reported the doubt about what is Orez and stated it as safek.
14. **But, even if Rice is not Orez, you need to bless AHM.**
15. But the [GRA](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1034) thinks that there is a printing error in Shulchan Aruch.
16. Mishna Berura [sk 47](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=232&hilite=) does has mentioned the Gra and advise a Yere Shamayim to eat such a bread inside a bread meal only, but he added that who want to maka as the SA said is allowed.
17. **But in your case, Safek Orez, may be that everybody agrees to the SA.**

---

#### list of abbreviations:

AHM: Al Hamichia;

BHM: Birkat Hamazon;

BMM: Bore Mine Mezonot;

KAP: Kezayt bikde Achilat Peras;

MM: Maggid Mishne;

OC: Orach Chayim;

SA: Shulchan Aruch;

sk: Sayif Katan;

Comment: oh my thank you so much for the in-depth answer! So l'maaseh I have who to rely on to make an AHM

Comment: @user3979986 I made a correction concerning the Mishna Berura

Comment: Triscuits aren't made with flour. They boil the grain kernals whole to soften them a bit, then dry them out and smash them into long threads, then pile the threads on top of each other and toast it. It's more of a OC 208:2 and OC 208:4 question.

Comment: @DoubleAA      The process you described was not known to me. I don't know ho to translat the process in Chazalic categories "חילקא טרגיס סולת זריז וערסן ואורז " . I need time to edit the answer. It is really interesting, I am wondering how poskim see the news processing like this and frozen they change the foods.